# How can I generate a plot from a hierarchically indexed group object such that I obtain two curves?

Tags: python, plot, pandas

I've transformed my data as follows:

```
s1 = pd.DataFrame({'soa': [500, -500, -500, -500, 500, 500],
                   'congruent': [True, True, True, False, False, False],
                   'is_correct': [True, True, False, False, False, False],
                   'some_stuff': pd.np.random.rand(6)})
subdf = s1[['congruent', 'soa', 'is_correct']]  # s1 is a DataFrame
m = subdf.groupby(('soa', 'congruent')).mean()
```

Displaying `m` in an ipython notebook gives me a very nice table:

[image]

I'd now like to plot two seperate curves, each with two points (-500 and 500).  One curve will be the condition in which `congruent == True` and the other will be the condition in which `congruent == False`.

I tried doing `m.plot()` but I get a single curve with a point for each multi-index tuple:

[image]

Knowing Pandas, I suspect there's an easy way to fix this -- any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @agstudy, it should be fairly trivial to mock up this data (I can't share it because of patient privacy issues).  Simply build a DataFrame with a few columns of random data, one of which should be boolean, and one of which should contain `500`s or `-500`s if you absolutely want the same values.

Comment: If it is so simple , why not to do it? The solution also is very simple in this case : you just need to reshape your data in the wide format, creating a new data_frame with 2 variable is_correct_True, and iscorrect_False the you call plot as usual.

Comment: @agstudy, Here you go:  `pd.DataFrame({'soa': [500, -500, -500, -500, 500, 500], 'congruent': [True, True, True, False, False, False], 'is_correct': [True, True, False, False, False, False], 'some_stuff': pd.np.random.rand(6)})`.  I'm not too clear on what your instructions are, however, could you kindly provide an example?

Comment: better to edit your question.

Comment: @agstudy, done.  I'd really appreciate an example, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after quite a bit of mucking about, I have a solution that does what I want, although I don't quite understand *how* it works...

```
s1 = pd.DataFrame({'soa': [500, -500, -500, -500, 500, 500],
               'congruent': [True, True, True, False, False, False],
               'is_correct': [True, True, False, False, False, False],
               'some_stuff': pd.np.random.rand(6)})
subdf = s1[['congruent', 'soa', 'is_correct']]  # s1 is a DataFrame
m = subdf.groupby(('soa', 'congruent')).mean()

m.unstack(level=1)
m.unstack(level=1).plot()
```

The results are shown below:

[image]

[image]

Pivot operations still confuse the hell out of me, so if someone can give me an intuition as to why `level=1` is the correct argument, I'd much appreciate it.  As best I can tell, `level` means something akin to *set this hierarchical index level as the table heading*.